# Making rotated adjustbox fit into cell

Tags: tables, rotating, tabularx

I tried `\rotatebox`, but was unable to make the rotated text vertically fit into one cell so I opted for `\adjustbox` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \label{tab:container}
  \caption{Some fancy table}
  \centering

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cl|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{
      \adjustbox{minipage=1cm,angle=90,raise={1pt}{0pt}{0pt}}{% raise by 1pt, set height and depth to 0pt.
        \RaggedRight
        Long rotated row title
      }
    }
    & Row 1 & & & &\\

    & Row 2 &&&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With `\adjustbox`, the above code yields:
[image]

I would like the text to be "centered" so that it "fits" between the `\hline`s of row 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're smashing the height/depth of the contents of your `\adjustbox` construction, you need something else to tell `\multirow` it has some height. I'll add a strut of height `2\normalbaselineskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% http://ctan.org/pkg/{multirow,adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow,adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \label{tab:container}
  \caption{Some fancy table}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cl|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{%
      \rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}% Vertical strut inserted
      \adjustbox{minipage=1cm,angle=90,raise={1pt}{0pt}{0pt}}{% raise by 1pt, set height and depth to 0pt.
        \RaggedRight
        Long rotated row title
      }
    }
    & Row 1 & & & & \\

    & Row 2 & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```